# SSRS Match Color series in stacked bar chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts, match, stacked

I have a stacked bar chart, with year on the x axis, and sales CY and sales LY on the y axis, also the bars are grouped (stacked) by company name, like in the picture below:
[bar chart stacked example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUQ0T.png)

The problem is I want to match the colors for the same companies, like: "united package CY" and "united package LY" have the same color for both, so will be easier to see the comparison between companies and years.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, click on your chart and go to the chart properties on the right side under:

**Chart > CustomPaletteColors**.

Here you can add your defined chart colurs for each series. For example if you have 4 series you have 4 different colors. You can set the color for series1 the same as series2.

Depending on which positions your series are, they will look like one section or they will have another color between them. But you can reorder the position of the series if you need to.

Comment: thanks a lot, but will be very difficult to apply this because the categories change a log between dates, so its not going to be a solution to put the colors for each of the series!